# Linked List inside Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to use nested linked lists, but I can't seem to access the inner part of the linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int option;

struct nodeAddr
{
  int idAddress;
  char address[50];
  struct nodeAddr *nextAddr;
}*headAddr,*tailAddr,*newAddr,*helpAddr;

struct nodePrs
{
    int idPersonel;
    char personel[50];
    struct nodeAddr *headAddr,*tailAddr,*newAddr,*helpAddr ;
    struct nodePrs *nextPrs;
}*headPrs,*tailPrs,*newPrs,*helpPrs;

void signUp()
{
    clrscr();
    printf("\t============================\n");
    printf("\t=   Sign Up New Personel   =\n");
    printf("\t============================\n\n");
    newPrs=(nodePrs*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodePrs));
    newPrs->newAddr=(nodeAddr*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeAddr));
    printf("Name : ");
    scanf("%s",newPrs->personel);
    printf("Address : ");
    scanf("%s",newPrs->newAddr->address);
    newPrs->nextPrs = NULL;
    newPrs->newAddr->nextAddr = NULL;
    if (headPrs==NULL)
    {
        headPrs = newPrs;
        headPrs->headAddr = newPrs->newAddr;
    }
    else
    {
        tailPrs->nextPrs=newPrs;
    }
    tailPrs=newPrs;
    tailPrs->tailAddr=newPrs->newAddr;
}

void printList()
{
    helpPrs = headPrs;
    nodePrs *temp = headPrs;
    if (headPrs==NULL)
        printf("Empty");
    else
    {
        printf("the Outputs:\n");
        while(helpPrs!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%s", helpPrs->personel);
            printf(" ");
            helpPrs->helpAddr = temp->headAddr;
            while (helpPrs->helpAddr !=NULL)
            {
                printf("%s", helpPrs->helpAddr->address);
                printf(" ");
                helpPrs->helpAddr = helpPrs->helpAddr->nextAddr;
            }
            helpPrs = helpPrs->nextPrs;
            temp=temp->nextPrs;
            printf("\n");
       }
    }
}

void main()
{
    do
    {
        clrscr();
        printf("\t==================================\n");
        printf("\t= Linked list inside Linked List =\n");
        printf("\t==================================\n\n");
        printf("1. Sign\n");
        printf("2. Show\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Input (1-3) : ");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        if (option == 1)
        {
            signUp();
        }
        else if (option == 2)
        {
            printList();
            getch();
        }
        else if(option>2 || option <1)
        {
            printf("Wrong choice!!!");
        }
    } while(option!=5);
    getch();
}
```

The problem is in the `printList()` function.  It only prints the first list. After that, it can't show its address of the second entry and so on.

Comment: This looks like C, not C++ (don't cast `malloc` in C, use smart pointers or container classes in C++). In other words, C != C++ for many "natural" solutions.

Comment: This looks like C++, not C

Comment: thanks for your advice. i learn this method from my school. they apparently also can't tells which c or c++, so how to allocate the memories in C++?

Comment: `void main()` is invalid. In C++ you would use new and delete, or preferably a smart pointer, or preferably just use `std::list`. It depends whether you just want to use a linked list, or the exercise is to create your own.

Comment: In C a struct definition is **not** a typedef. In C++ it is.

Comment: i had to use linked list...

Comment: in c++ we use new operator to allocate memory and delete operator to release memory. these operators call constructor and destructor respectively.

Comment: Not sure why you have tail and header pointers  for nodeAddr  when you are accepting only one address for each  nodePrs.If you are capturing multiple address for each personnel then your singup() function  logic is wrong.

Comment: the tail is for mark of the very end of the node so i can insert new node  behind the tail.. but thanks for noticing that i might going to change it afterall